# How to mock Autofac IComponentContext.Resolve<IRepository>

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, autofac

I am looking how to mock autofac Resolve method. I am using NUnit and NSubstitute for unit tests.
I have a Business method which calls Repository method, and inside business method, i am using

**_container.Resolve< IRepository>().GetData()==> here _container is IComponentContext.**

Instead of calling real db, i want to mock repository method, but i am not able to do that, every time this line tries to call real db.

In my unit tests, I am trying to mock like this....

**private IRepository _Repository;**

**_repository = Substitute.For< IRepository>();**

**_repository.GetData().Returns("abc");**

Answer (score 0):

**Don't try to mock dependency injection.** Instead of mocking DI, register your mock with Autofac.

This may mean that you need to modify your code so it allows you to add registrations to the container in a test scenario. In ASP.NET Core they have [a notion of `ConfigureTestServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for example that allows you to put registrations in a method that only get run in a test scenario.

Another way to do it is to [use a custom Startup class](https://dzone.com/articles/using-a-custom-startup-class-with-aspnet-core-inte) where all the methods are virtual so you can override `ConfigureServices` or `ConfigureContainer` to register test overrides.

Unfortunately, *exactly how* you do this is so very application specific that there's not "one way to do it" or a "best practice." You're going to have to do some searching and looking at your own app to figure it out.

However, the takeaway here is: **Don't try to mock DI. Use real DI with mocks inside the container.**

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and i dealt with it by not mocking the Container (as Travis suggested), but instead building a real Container and configuring it to return my Mock.

I dunno if this is the best way but below is how i did it, adapting to your problem:

```
private IContainer _container;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    //Setup your mocked repository here...

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register(x => myMockedRepository).As<IRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    _container = builder.build();
}

[TestCase]
public void MyTestCase()
{
    //Use _container.Resolve<IRepository> in your test...
    //or
    //pass your _container as the IComponentContext where needed...
}
```